# Por que esta sentencia SQL da error de NON-Object en PHP?

Tags: php, mysqli

Tengo la siguiente tabla llamada **Ordenes**:

```
Ordenes: 
id_orden = entero 
id_producto = entero
```

Ejemplo de registros:

```
id_orden - id_producto
1        - 2
1        - 3
1        - 14
1        - 7
```

Quisiera obtener todos los `id_producto` que tenga un `id_orden` especifico, por lo que consigo antes los `id_orden`sin repeticion:

```
$sql= "SELECT DISTINCT id_orden FROM ordenes"; 
$sentencia1= $conexion->prepare($sql);
$sentencia1->execute();
$sentencia1->bind_result($id);
while ($sentencia1->fetch()) {

echo $id;

 $sql= "SELECT id_producto FROM ordenes WHERE id_orden=?"; 

 $sentencia2=$conexion->prepare($sql);

 $sentencia2->bind_param("i",$id);
 $sentencia2->execute();
 $sentencia2->bind_result($producto);

 while ($sentencia2->fetch()){
 echo "<td>".$producto."</td>";
 }
}
```

Me sale el siguiente error:

```
Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object en la linea donde esta el bind_param
```

Aqui la conexión:

```
<?php
$conexion = new mysqli("localhost","root","","produccion");
?>
```

**Como puedo conseguir cada `id_orden` y a la vez todos los `id_producto` que tengan ese mismo `id_orden`?**

**Nota:** es posible convertir esos dos SELECT en un JOIN?

Comment: Me parece que le faltan datos a la pregunta. Tienes la tabla Ordenes y quieres todos los registros cuyo `id_orden` sea igual a 1 por ejemplo. Si es eso, usando un `WHERE id_orden=1` sería suficiente. Para hacer `JOIN` debería existir otra tabla, quizá exista pero no haces mención de ella por ningún lado en la pregunta. En cuanto al error que te está dando, parece indicar que `$conexion` no existe... tampoco dices de donde sacas la variable `$conexion`, sin duda debería ser la variable que obtiene un objeto de conexión a la BD, pero puede que la misma no se esté realizando como esperas.

Comment: @A.Cedano leyendo en internet consegui que el error esta en el **execute()**, no puede usarse dentro de un while. por lo que se recomienda hacer un INNER JOIN de las tablas, en este caso se debe AUTOREFERENCIAR la tabla:

SELECT DISTINCT a.id_orden , b.id_producto FROM ordenes a JOIN ordenes b ON a.id_orden=b.id_orden

Pero me muestra las id_orden repetidas, 1-2-3-1-2-3-1-2-3, como hago para hacer el DISTINCT de id_orden y id_producto muestre todos los datos

Comment: No alcanzo a entender el problema que planteas, pero percibo que estás confundido con lo que quieres hacer, **no tiene ningún sentido en este caso hacer un INNER JOIN de una tabla consigo misma** cuando puedes filtrar los datos mediante `WHERE columna_id=1`por ejemplo. Creo que deberías tener dos tablas: una llamada `ordenes` y otra llamada `productos`, entonces sí podrías hacer el `JOIN` entre ambas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He creado un posible modelo de lo que (intuyo) quieres hacer, el cual, creo, podría ayudarte a repensar la forma en que estás organizando tus datos.

El modelo tiene las siguientes tablas:

- `productos` : donde estarían todos los detalles de cada producto
- `clientes`  : estarían todos los detalles de cada cliente
- `ordenes`   : registraría cada orden en particular con un id, la fecha, y otros campos ...
- `ordenes_productos` : guardaría todos los productos que se han pedido en cada orden, evitando tener que repetir los datos que ya existen en las tablas productos, ordenes, clientes. Esto se llama una tabla asociativa.

Podría tener más tablas, todas ellas relacionadas entre sí, por ejemplo, una tabla `inventario`, una tabla `ordenes_tipo` para órdenes a crédito, al contado, etc., una tabla `proveedores`, etc, etc.

Las consultas **Query 1, Query 2 y Query 3** filtran las órdenes por el id de producto. Pero puedes igualmente hacer cualquier tipo de filtro. Por ejemplo, puedes filtrar todas las órdenes de un cliente específico, todas las órdenes de una fecha específica, los productos más vendidos, los productos que no tienen ninguna venta... si amplías el modelo podrías obtener la cantidad de productos disponibles en inventario, etc, etc. Las posibilidades son enormes, con un diseño bien elaborado y **todo se haría con una sola consulta SQL** aplicando los `JOIN` adecuadamente.

El ejemplo que te muestro es algo básico, esperando que puedas captar la idea en general.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b7741d/1)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE productos
    (`producto_id` int, `producto_nom` varchar(50), `producto_precio` decimal)
;

INSERT INTO productos
    (`producto_id`, `producto_nom`, `producto_precio`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Pan', 0.90),
    (2, 'Vino', 2.00),
    (3, 'Aceite', 1.12)
;

CREATE TABLE clientes
    (`cliente_id` int, `cliente_nom` varchar(50))
;

INSERT INTO clientes
    (`cliente_id`, `cliente_nom`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Pedro'),
    (2, 'Santiago'),
    (3, 'Juan')
;

CREATE TABLE ordenes
    (`orden_id` int, `cliente_id` int, `orden_fecha` date)
;

INSERT INTO ordenes
    (`orden_id`, `cliente_id`, `orden_fecha`)
VALUES
    (1, 1, '2017-05-10'),
    (2, 2, '2017-05-11'),
    (3, 3, '2017-05-12'),
    (4, 3, '2017-05-13'),
    (5, 1, '2017-05-15')
;

CREATE TABLE ordenes_productos
    (`orden_id` int, `producto_id` int, `cantidad` int)
;

INSERT INTO ordenes_productos
    (`orden_id`, `producto_id`, `cantidad`)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 100),
    (1, 3, 5),
    (2, 1, 500),
    (2, 2, 200),
    (3, 1, 643),
    (3, 2, 980)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
-- Clientes que han comprado producto 1
SELECT
  p.producto_id, p.producto_nom, c.cliente_nom, o.orden_fecha
FROM
  ordenes_productos op
INNER JOIN 
  ordenes o ON op.orden_id=o.orden_id
INNER JOIN 
  productos p ON op.producto_id=p.producto_id
INNER JOIN 
  clientes c ON o.cliente_id=c.cliente_id
WHERE p.producto_id=1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b7741d/1/0)**:

```
| producto_id | producto_nom | cliente_nom |           orden_fecha |
|-------------|--------------|-------------|-----------------------|
|           1 |          Pan |       Pedro | May, 10 2017 00:00:00 |
|           1 |          Pan |    Santiago | May, 11 2017 00:00:00 |
|           1 |          Pan |        Juan | May, 12 2017 00:00:00 |
```

**Query 2**:

```
-- Clientes que han comprado producto 2
SELECT
  p.producto_id, p.producto_nom, c.cliente_nom, o.orden_fecha
FROM
  ordenes_productos op
INNER JOIN 
  ordenes o ON op.orden_id=o.orden_id
INNER JOIN 
  productos p ON op.producto_id=p.producto_id
INNER JOIN 
  clientes c ON o.cliente_id=c.cliente_id
WHERE p.producto_id=2
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b7741d/1/1)**:

```
| producto_id | producto_nom | cliente_nom |           orden_fecha |
|-------------|--------------|-------------|-----------------------|
|           2 |         Vino |    Santiago | May, 11 2017 00:00:00 |
|           2 |         Vino |        Juan | May, 12 2017 00:00:00 |
```

**Query 3**:

```
-- Clientes que han comprado producto 3
SELECT
  p.producto_id, p.producto_nom, c.cliente_nom, o.orden_fecha
FROM
  ordenes_productos op
INNER JOIN 
  ordenes o ON op.orden_id=o.orden_id
INNER JOIN 
  productos p ON op.producto_id=p.producto_id
INNER JOIN 
  clientes c ON o.cliente_id=c.cliente_id
WHERE p.producto_id=3
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b7741d/1/2)**:

```
| producto_id | producto_nom | cliente_nom |           orden_fecha |
|-------------|--------------|-------------|-----------------------|
|           3 |       Aceite |       Pedro | May, 10 2017 00:00:00 |
```

Comment: Excelente respuesta, luego lo que queria era que en vez del producto id salir varias veces, en la tabla se mostrara una sola vez, ocurre que el sistema lo hizo un amigo y me pidio ayuda para ello, por eso esa estructura y lo creo, es que las ordenes la hace una misma persona, porque como tal, los productos son productos de oficina y ellos no es que se venden sino que se trasladan entre oficinas de un departamento

Comment: Tambien me ayudaron en stackoverflow.com: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44148003/how-can-i-show-only-one-time-a-repeat-record-and-all-of-the-other-different-elem

Comment: Pero sabes hay algo que no logro entender, porque me da error el execute dentro del while si yo he utilizado demasiadas veces sentencias dentro del while? sera porque la forma en la que se muestran los resultdos de la primera sentencia?

Comment: @Victor - Random tener un execute dentro de un while no es recomendable imagina que ese while por algún motivo no salga nunca uff la BD terminaría al menos quedando down por algún tiempo. Aparte de que para lo que quieres hacer, con un solo SELECT sería suficiente. Si de todos modos quieres mandar varias consultas a la BD existen formas de crear consultas dinámicas en las cuales puedes crear todas las consultas y pasarlas en un solo execute. También se pueden usar transacciones para resolver problemas más avanzados. Creo que la dificultad en el problema que planteas está en el diseño de la BD

Comment: Si eso veo yo, porque hay maneras mas fáciles, Lo que hice al final fue hacer dos JOIN pero antes habria en otros casos realizado el execute dentro del while pero tienes razon en lo que dices, sera que me podrias ayudar en ese sentido? explicarme esos otros modos, claro esta cuando tengas tiempos :).

Por cierto, comenzare a ser sistemas de prueba utilizando la libreria PDO que me diste :) gracias :) jejeje